# duplicate title using jm-chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl in Juris-M

Tags: reference, bibliography

When I format the reference using  jm-chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl in Juris-M, the title occurs twice, does someone know the reason?

Many thanks.

Example:

[1] MINEKUS M, ALMINGER M, ALVITO P, et al. A standardised static in vitro digestion method suitable for food – an international consensus
A standardised static in vitro digestion method suitable for food – an international consensus[J]. Food & Function, 2014, 5(6) : 1113–1124

The address of the reference https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/fo/c3fo60702j#!divAbstract

Gist of the csl file:
https://gist.github.com/redleafnew/6f6fa23c3627c67d968eee38e4d2d40a

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed. Replace

```
 <text macro="title" suffix="[J]."/>
 <text value=""/>
```

with

```
<text value="[J]."/>
```

The duplicated reference could be removed.